# What is the Pre-Open-Event for files in Word VSTO

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'm trying to make an *add-in* in C# for Word and I need to process things before that document has been opened by Word.

There is an *Open* event, but it is called/executed *after* the document has been opened by Word.

But I need to process data **before** the document is opened.
Does anybody now how this kind of event is named?

Comment: I (hopefully) improved the question by clarifying what is really desired.